# Error when running Powershell script for User list

Tags: 2013

I am getting an error when trying to run a powershell script.  I copied this script from a site.  It should take fields from the user information list which is hidden and populate  a contact list that you have created an advance.  I am not a powershell user so I copied the script as is and tried to run it from powershell by typing .\CreateEmployeeDirectory

I am getting the following error:

```
At C:\Users\me\CreateEmployeeDirectory.ps1:19 char:162
+ ... ist $webUrl } |
+                    ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

Here is the script:

```
cls
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}
function Enumerate-SPUserProfiles($webUrl, $listName)
{
    $x= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
    $x= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("microsoft.sharepoint.portal")
    $x= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")
    $x= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
    $sites = Get-SPSite
    $context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($sites[0])
    $profileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    $list = $web.Lists[$listName]

    # gets all the user profiles, those that have domain\username as DisplayName are excluded
    $profileManager.GetEnumerator() | ?{$_.DisplayName -notlike '*\*' -and $_.ProfileType -eq "User" } | foreach-object { Update-PhoneBook $_ $web $list $webUrl } |
}

function Update-PhoneBook($user, $web, $list, $webUrl)
{
    if($user.Item("FirstName") -ne "" -and $user.Item("FirstName") -ne $null)
    {
        $spQuery = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
        $userName = $user.Item("UserName")
        $camlQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='Text'>$userName</Value></Eq></Where>";
        $spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
        $spQuery.RowLimit = 1
        $spListItemCollection = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
        $domain = (gwmi WIN32_ComputerSystem).Domain

        if($spListItemCollection.Count -ge 1)
        {
            Write-Host "Updating $username..."
            Update-Contact $spListItemCollection[0] $user $domain $webUrl
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Adding $username..."
            $contact = $list.items.add();
            Update-Contact $contact $user $domain $webUrl
        }
    }
}

function Update-Contact($contact, $user, $domain, $webUrl)
{
    $lastName = $user.Item("LastName");
    $contact["Title"] = "$lastName";

    $firstName = $user.Item("FirstName");
    $contact["FirstName"] = "$firstName";

    $workEmail = $user.Item("WorkEmail");
    $contact["Email"] = "$workEmail";

    $workPhone = $user.Item("WorkPhone");
    $contact["WorkPhone"] = "$workPhone";

    $CellPhone = $user.Item("CellPhone");
    $contact["CellPhone"] = "$cellPhone";

    $office = $user.Item("Office");
    $contact["Office"] = "$office";

    $department = $user.Item("Department");
    $contact["Department"] = "$department";

    $userName = $user.Item("UserName");
    $contact["UserName"] = "$userName";

    $contact.update()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, this line is wrong:

`$profileManager.GetEnumerator() | ?{$_.DisplayName -notlike '*\*' -and $_.ProfileType -eq "User" } | foreach-object { Update-PhoneBook $_ $web $list $webUrl } |`

Please try replacing it with this one here (note that the last |-character is now gone):

`$profileManager.GetEnumerator() | ?{$_.DisplayName -notlike '*\*' -and $_.ProfileType -eq "User" } | foreach-object { Update-PhoneBook $_ $web $list $webUrl }`

Comment: Thanks Daniel that allowed it to run but now I have a different issue.  I was expecting it to ask for the two values that are in the Enumerator but when I run it it just executes without asking for input.  Should I be including the input value some way when I issue the run command of .\CreateEmployeeDirectory.  Also I got this message once it did finish: The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.  Should I be concerned with that message?

Comment: Without rewriting the script, you will have to call the function directly ( e.g. 'Enumerate-SPUserProfiles "your_site_url" "List_Name"'). Yes, you should be concerned about that message. It can have a few reasons, though, so you might want to ask about it in a separate question.